# How to exclude default application.properties add custom properties file using profiles in maven for spring boot project?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, war, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have developed a web application using spring boot. I have three resource folders in src/main/resources staging,qa,production which consists of application properties and logging configuration for the specific environment. Along with these folders I have application.properties and  logging configuration in resources folder which I use it for dev environment. I want to package war file according to the environment using spring-boot-maven plugin. I am new to maven any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 2):

Convetion is `application-{profileName}.properties`

Point 10 and 11:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

e.g `application-test.properties`
it overrides the `application.properties`
Make profile in `pom.xml`

Introduction to profiles:
http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: It works for application.properties. What should I do for other configuration files(example logging).

Comment: Can you tell me more about this `logging configuration for the specific environment` ?
Are you sure that you can not create variables in `application.properties` that will do the stuff  and change them based on your needs?

Comment: log file paths will be different in each environment. We can create variables in application.properties files, but application.properties doesn't allow to completely configure log4j2, so I am using xml configuration files specific for each environment. What if I want to deploy war in external container, I couldn't pass active profiles information during deployment. Do you have any solution to pass only environment  specific properties while packaging the war?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using Maven to add different folders to your classpath for each environment, you can use Spring profiles.

First of all create different **application.properties** for each environment, such as:

- application-staging.properties
- application-qa.properties
- application-production.properties

For the logging you can use the `logging.config` property. So, in **application-staging.properties** you could use:

```
logging.config=classpath:logback-staging.xml
```

In the other properties files you can use different `logging.config` properties.

Now just run your application with the `spring.profiles.active` property.

---

However, an easier solution would be to use [externalized configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html). Rather than having to rebuild each time you want to change configuration for a specific profile, you can externalize it by putting an **application.properties** file next to your JAR/WAR in the correct environment, rather than on your classpath. Spring boot will pick this up automatically.

Now you can also externalize your logging config by placing a logback.xml (or log4j2.xml, ...) file next to your JAR/WAR and just configure your (externalized) application properties with:

```
logging.config=file:logback.xml
```

This allows you to edit your configuration and logging without having to change your JAR/WAR.

Comment: While deploying in external tomcat container, I just add the war file to the webapps folder and restart the container. So, I have to add correct application.properties file while packaging the war. How can I achieve this during packaging time. 
>>>>


Just run your application with spring.profiles.active meaning 
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=staging(Is this what you are trying to say)

Comment: Yes, using `-Dspring.profiles.active=staging` should work. You should also be able to configure this property in your Tomcat container.